# Install custom .NET Standard NuGet Package in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have made my own NuGet package which is target framework is .NET STandard 2.0

These are the dependencies for my package:

```
<dependencies>
        <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
            <dependency id="Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetStd" version="1.7.2.4114" />
            <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version="2.1.1" />
            <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" />            
        </group>
    </dependencies>
```

When i try to install my package in a .Net Core 2.1 Web API, i get these errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning NU1701  Package 'Apache.NMS 1.7.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   NU1701  Package 'Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.7.2' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

Comment: I created a basic nuget package with a .net std 2.0 class library with apache.mns.activemq.netstd 1.7.2.4114 in it and then created a .net core 2.1 web api project and added the package to it without any warnings or errors.....  It should work.  I can't really diagnose more with what you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

Install the .NET Core version:

[Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore/)

The package you referenced doesn't target `.NET Standard` and thus you get the warning.

Comment: Yes, but Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetCore is not compatible with .NET Standard

Comment: The dependency appears to be the .NetStd version (Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetStd)